# Script for opening corresponding pdfs for bibtex keys in Vim

Tags: vim, find

#### Context

I currently write research articles in LaTeX using Vim.
I have bibtex keys in my articles like `\cite{smith2000sometopic}` and I have corresponding pdf versions of most articles in a subfolder of `~/lib` e.g., `~/lib/topica/smith2000sometopic.pdf`.

#### Aim

I'd like to be able to press a key in Vim when my cursor is over a bibtex key that:

1. extracts the `bibtex-key` under the cursor
2. performs a search for `bibtex-key.pdf`
3. if the file is found, opens the file in a pdf viewer
4. If the file is not found, indicate that this is the case

#### Question

- Has anyone already done something like this?
- Are there any examples that would be useful to study?

#### Initial thoughts

I thought I could use something like:

```
 gnome-open `find ~/lib/ -iname "smith2000sometopic.pdf" | head -1`
```

and then experiment with some Vimscript to fine tune the interaction; but if anyone has any examples or suggestions, that would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, I should have persisted a little longer before posting, but any suggestions for improvement are still more than welcome.

In the end I found this [documentation useful from vimtips](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Online_documentation_for_word_under_cursor).

This was the Vim function I wrote:

```
function! OpenBibtexPDF()
    let s:word = expand("<cword>")
    let s:cmd = "!gnome-open `find ~/lib/ -iname '" . s:word . ".pdf' | head -1`"
    execute s:cmd
endfunction 
map <silent> <leader>bb :call OpenBibtexPDF()<cr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on Jeromy Anglim's answer, I modified a bit his code.

This can be used without gnome, it uses "zenity" for error display, and zathura as pdf viewer (just change it to whichever you prefer).
I also added the mapping for a double click on the word (even if using the mouse is not the vim-mindset)

```
function! OpenBibtexPDF()
    let s:word = expand("<cword>")
    let s:cmd = 'silent !pathfile=$(find ~/lib -iname "' . s:word . '*.pdf" -print -quit 2>/dev/null); [ -z "$pathfile" ] && zenity --info --width=250 --text="Pdf related to this this entry is not found" || zathura "$pathfile" >/dev/null &'
    execute s:cmd | redraw!
endfunction 
map <silent> <leader>bb :call OpenBibtexPDF()<cr>
map <silent> <2-LeftMouse> :call OpenBibtexPDF()<cr>
```